# How to compare the values of three matrices are equal?

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

I'm new to Matlab. I need help with matrix comparison.

I have three matrices: **R**, **S** and **T** (size: *95956 x 1*) and I need to compare all of their elements and see which elements are equal. Then we multiply the same values by a fourth matrix.

In a Matlab file, I read the coordinates and separate them into three matrices. Thus obtaining matrices R, S and T saved in "data.mat". Then I read in another file "data.mat" and used a `For` loop:

```
for t=1:1:length(CoordinateIndex)
    index = R == S;
    ts=ts+1;
end
```

Is this correct and how I will multiply only those values which are equal to a fourth matrix?

Comment: Are the equal values in the same position in all three matrices?

Comment: Hi Brasofilo. 

Not every one of the matrices has 95956 values ​​spread in a column. What I need is to check for equal values​​. For example: In the matrix R is a value 0.2589 I need to check if the matrix S and T is the value matris 0.2589.

Please could you help me to proceed in this matter. Thank you very much

Are you Brazilian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some simple example matrices and [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1), we can find the values that are common among all three via:

```
R = [1:4 1:4 1:4 1:4];
S = [1:2 1:2 1:4 1:6 1:2];
T = [1:6 1:2 1:8];
R_common = R(R==S&R==T);
```

This produces:

```
R_common =

     1     2     1     2     3     4
```

If you want the indices that are common among all three matrices, use:

```
I = find(R==S&R==T);
```

which gives

```
I = 
     1     2     9    10    11    12
```

**EDIT**: As @Adiel suggested, you may be interested in the values that are common among the matrices regardless of their location in the matrices. This can be accomplished simply via the [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) function (also see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/14592)):

```
RST_intersection = intersect(intersect(R,S),T)
```

For my example matrices this gives

```
RST_intersection =

     1     2     3     4
```

Note that the arguments to `intersect` can be different lengths, which may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Horchler

Thank so much for helping me, as I said I am new in using MatLab. Whenever I use the commands R_common = R(R==S&R==T); and I = find(R==S&R==T);, I got the following response:Empty matrix: 0-by-1.

Please could you continue to help me in this matter. thank you very much

Comment: @Jadielcsilva This mean that there are no common values in the SAME locations at all three matrices. Do you need equal values in same locations, or general equal values (for example, is `S(1)=R(12)` good?) ?

Comment: @Jadielcsilva: you can detect the case where there were no common values with the [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) function.

Comment: Hi
First I would like to thank everyone for help. I need to know what are the values ​​that are common among mothers, regardless of their location in the arrays. I believe that the function u showed me Horchler provides these values​​. I'll do some testing. Thanks again and help from you guys.

Comment: But the "intersect" shows which row values ​​are equal, and now I need to multiply the values ​​contained in these lines with a fourth matrix (D). How to do this because I have now only lines which have equal values​​. If I multiply RST_intersection with the matrix (D) is not correct because it is only the position RST_intersection lines q contains the same values ​​and not the values​​. Guys, excuse me so uncomfortable, but I'm learning to work with matrices in MATLAB and you guys have helped me a lot.  Please help me again

Comment: @Jadielcsilva: I'm not exactly sure what you're describing. But it sounds like a separate question. If you can't solve it by searching Google and this site, you should carefully formulate it (with an example and simple code illustrating what you're trying to do) and post a new question. Cheers.